# Pi-matching impedance calculation for LoRa 868Mhz RFM95

Tags: rf, impedance-matching

I'm not an expert in RF, but I'm interested in understanding how to calculate an RF matching circuit for my [RFM95W 868M](https://www.hoperf.com/data/upload/portal/20190301/RFM95_96_97_98W.pdf) LoRa node that indicates pin ANT terminated in a matched 50 ohm impedance matching.

At the output of the matching circuit, I want to connect a wire antenna or an RP-SMA connector like [this.](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2012241212_HJ-Tech-HJ-SMA241_C1509216.pdf)

I've readed around and I've found this [tool](https://www.eeweb.com/tools/pi-match/) that can be used to calculate the RF matching circuit.

This is how I've placed my frequency (F=868) reference, my source resistance (RS=50) and my load resistance (RL=50.) The output is the following:

[image]

I have two main questions:

1. Let's suppose that the calculation are okay, which commercial parts/values I can use?
2. The Q factor can be 3? Must it be higher? Lower? Is there a "rule of thumb?"

Comment: Did you read this , https://www.hoperf.com/data/upload/back/20181122/ANTENNAS_MODULE.pdf

Comment: If the source is 50Ω and the antenna is 50Ω, then no matching required, they're already matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *This is how i've placed my Frequency (F=868) reference, my Source
> resistance \$\color{red}{\text{(RS=50)}}\$ and my Load Resistance \$\color{red}{\text{(RL=50)}}\$*

Your source and load impedances are identical so, you have no need to match them. The pi network will give you some filtering benefits but that's a different question.

---

> *The Q factor can be 3? Must it be higher? Lower? Is there a "rule of
> thumb?"*

Here's where there's a bit of controversy as to what Q factor actually means. [This document](http://www.arrl.org/files/file/QEX_Next_Issue/2015/Sep-Oct_2015/Kaune.pdf) (entitled Quality Factor, Bandwidth, and Harmonic Attenuation of Pi Networks) discusses what the so-called Q factor is in pi filters and concludes that it can mean different things to different people.

Significantly, the on-line calculators that invoke Q factor as a parameter don't appear to justify what it means or how to use it. Think about a pi filter of equal input and output impedance; the circuit gain has to be unity hence, Q factor should be unity basically because: -

$$Q = A_V = \sqrt{\dfrac{R_L}{R_{IN}}}$$

On [my basic website](http://stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20PI%20LP.html) I don't use Q factor because of the ambiguity stated above. I derive the pi network as two back-to-back L-pads like this: -

[image]

\$R_X\$ would be the output impedance of the left hand L-pad or the input impedance of the right-hand L-pad. Of course, when placed back-to-back they fully interlock as matching impedances AND, \$R_X\$ is unambiguous in that respect. For instance, if I use my calculator at 868 MHz I get the same results as the calculator you used when \$R_X\$ is 5 Ω: -

[image]

And, if I vary \$R_X\$ you can see it is peakier in the response as \$R_X\$ gets lower: -

[image]

Incidentally, the graph above is when \$R_{IN}\$ = 50 Ω and \$R_L\$ = 300 Ω. So, decide yourself whether you want to use Q or want to use \$R_X\$. As a last resort, you can always simulate the circuit to look at the frequency response.

Comment: RS and RL = 50 Ohm maybe are placed wrong...i mean the source resistance needs to be 50 ohm as specified in the datasheet and the antenna *may* be matched to be at 50 ohm; idk, i feel a little bit confused on that.

Comment: It sounds like you don't need matching because they are inherently matched @VirtApp